# JS - Get value on click event from dyamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get value on click event from dynamically added elements but something goes wrong.

My code is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#myContainer").append("<div class='remove' value='myValue'>click to display value</div>"); 
        });
        $(document).on("click", ".remove" , function() {     
            alert($(this).val());  
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Add new list item</button>
    <div id="myContainer">
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

When I am clicking on the created dynamically `div` there is empty alert insted of `myValue`.

What should I change?

Comment: Hi Rash, if you move the <script> tag bellow you <body> tag, probably the problem will be fixed.

Comment: @OscarVelandia unfortunatelly not

Comment: This got nothing to do with the location of the script. A `div` element doesn't have `.val()`, try `.attr('value')` instead

Comment: @AlonEitan is correct. You're thinking about input elements, which natively have val(). You added a non-native attribute to your <div>, so you would fetch it as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

**Try**

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove" , function() {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

**Instead of**

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove" , function() {     
    alert($(this).val());  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you. ↓↓

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#myContainer").append("<div class='remove' value='myValue'>click to display value</div>"); 
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".remove" , function() {     
    alert($(this).attr('value'));  
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Add new list item</button>
  <div id="myContainer"> </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, I have updated the answer, hope that helps. :)